# Get the value of the first argument of the ternary expression

Tags: groovy

I would like to get to use the value of the first argument in a ternary expression to do something like:

```
a() ? b(value of a()) : c
```

Is there a way to do this? a is a function that is costly to run multiple times and that return a list. I need to make different computations if the list is null.
I want to express it in a ternary expression.

I tried to do something like:

```
String a()
{
    "a"
}

def x
(x=a()) ? println(x) : println("not a")
```

But it's quite ugly...

Comment: Could you please put it in a wider context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could maybe wrap it in a with?

```
def result = a().with { x -> x ? "Got $x" : "Nope" }
```

Comment: Nice @tim_yates! Looks great :)

Comment: @Heschoon there was a bug in Groovy 1.8 (ish) where `with` didn't work with `null`, but I believe it was fixed :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a groovy collect:

```
def result = a().collect { "Got $it" } ?: "Nope"
```

If you are worried about your a() returning a list containing nulls you can use findAll.

```
def result = a().findAll { it }.collect { "Got $it" } ?: "Nope"
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's possible with ternary operator, however maybe memoization is the solution:

```
Closure<String> a = {
    'a'
}.memoize()

a() ? println(a()) : println("not a")
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
Something tmp = a()
tmp ? b(tmp) : c
```

Comment: Nice, but I would want to get rid of the Variable declaration; I don't need the value of a().